# Can't Boot in Recovery Mode (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, xfce, recovery-mode

Normal boot works (sort of) while in recovery mode hangs before the login.

Recently I've had a problem with [Xfce desktop not loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337219/xfce-desktop-environment-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-not-loading) except through recovery mode, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401423/recovery-mode-freezes-and-no-options-turning-up):

1. While in GRUB and on the recovery menu entry press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the menu entry.
2. Remove the `nomodeset` parameter from the line starting with `linux`.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot with the modified kernel command line.

It resolves the issue, except unlike before it doesn't fully load the Xfce desktop environment. Do I have other options to get back what worked before?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED, FIXED, RESOLVED etc. In the question title. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from recovery mode of the kernel correctly installed, the one with '**ii**' initials for both linux-modules and linux-modules-extra, check `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules` I've reinstalled the one being actually used.
to check which one is it:

`uname -r`

to reinstall (in my case linux-modules-extra of the used kernel had '**ic**' initials):

`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-*kernel name*`