# Won't boot normally or from recovery mode - no internet connection (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, dell, intel

I had unresolved previous [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338354/cant-boot-in-recovery-mode-ubuntu-20-04) booting from recovery mode, now nothing seems to work and normal booting also gets stuck before the login. when loading this message appears:

> Failed to start System Logging Service. See systemctl status rsyslog.service for details

from there it says it's active and running.

Connection through wifi, tethering usb and tethering bluetooth isn't working. with `ip a` no address shows up. I don't know if the two are connected.

any kind of help would be very appreciated

Comment: This is now the 3rd chainloaded question with only inconsistent references to the OS (Ubuntu/Xubuntu), no hardware specifications or something relevant. Please edit the question and provide relevant information, describe why you had nomodeset in the first place and what led to only booting in recovery mode, at least.

Comment: sorry that's because I literally don't know what are relevant informations, aside from editing in Intel GPU, what else do I need to add? I am that useless, I don't know how I got nomodeset or what it is and the reason for trying to boot in recovery mode was my first issue 'xfce desktop environment not loading'.

Comment: Did you installed XFCE?

Comment: no, it come with the pc when I bought it

Comment: Perhaps better to reinstall.

Comment: I had already tried, purge then 'apt-get install --reinstall xfce4', should I give it another go from root?  edit: forgot it won't connect to internet though

Comment: I meant to reinstall the OS. But yes, in order to use apt you need root (sudo) and an internet connection.

Comment: I really don't want to make any more mistakes, how do I solve the network stuff first? 'ip a' or 'ifconfig' doesn't show mine or other address

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED, FIXED, RESOLVED etc. In the question title. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my computer is a Dell latitude e6410, from bios setup (F12 at power-up) I deselected everything in the wireless switch section. bluetooth, then after rebooting also wifi reactivated. I repaired and upgraded from recovery mode of the actually only kernel correctly installed, the one with '**ii**' initials for both linux-modules and linux-modules-extra `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules`

In all of this the 'Failed to start System Logging Service' message never disappeared.